# Confluence - multiple page export to word

Tags: confluence

I can export a single Confluence page to Word, but if I try multiple page export (via `Space tools->Export`). I only have HTML, XML and PDF as options. How do I export multiple Confluence pages to Word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done via the [Page Tree Word Exporter](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.metainf.confluence.plugin.pagetreeexporter.pagetree-word-exporter-plugin) plugin.

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a new wiki page
2. Use the `{include}` macro to pull content in from several pages one at a time
3. Tools > Export to Word

Comment: The built in export function for Confluence does not exporting multiple pages to Word.

Comment: This worked for me, but the {include} didn't bring in the page title.

Comment: The include page macro only pulls in the page contents. You could write a user macro to wrap around the page macro to also pull in the page title for each page as a header, or construct the page headers manually. We had a macro for which you could pass the top of a page tree, which the user macro then listed all of the current children and displayed the contents of each with a header so the display page was not static. The power of Confluence user macros :)

Comment: It doesn't even export to Word. If you select "export to Word", It exports to a mail multipart MIME message with a `text/html`  content (so not Microsoft's "Open XML" format), generated by JavaMail, encoded "quoted-printable" to add insult to injury. Bletch.

Answer (score 6):

From any space within Confluence in "more options" choose **View in Hierarchy** and then go to the **Export** tab as shown below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The question asked as how to export as Word.

Comment: Yeah - but PDF might achieve the desired result.   I wish I had scrolled further down and found this answer before acting on an earlier answer.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open **Space Tools** > **Export**
2. Select **PDF Export**
3. Select the pages to export
4. Click <kbd>Export</kbd> and save the resulting PDF file
5. Open the PDF file in Microsoft Word 2013
   Right-click > Open with > Word (desktop)
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to convert it. 
   Word will now convert your PDF to an editable Word document.
7. Fix any serious issues caused by the PDF to Word conversion
   For example delete the header and footer if required, and the first page if it is blank.
8. Save as a word document
   **File** > **Save As** > **Browse** > <kbd>Save</kbd>

The main drawback to this approach is that it is quite manual.

- Manual export of multiple pages to PDF.
- Manual fixing of display issues in Word, in particular the header and footer.

Otherwise, the result was acceptable.

Comment: I don't have `export` in the `Space Tools`

Comment: Ask your space administrator for [Space Export permission](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/space-permissions-overview-139521.html) (note: block cdn.evgnet.com before opening that page)

Answer (score 0):

You can export multiple pages from Confluence to Word at one go using the [Scroll Office](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.scroll.scroll-office/cloud/overview) plug-in. You can create a customized MS Word template according to the needs of your organization and upload that template on Confluence (may need Admin rights to upload).

Then go to Confluence and simply export the desired set of pages by selecting the uploaded template and manually configuring a few export settings provided by the plug-in.

The result is awesome considering the quality of the Word template that you have created.

Comment: Gotta try this. I suppose Confluence sucks horribly at export even after 15 years of development to leave market space for plugins that do something useful ...